# Question on manipulation step of trigonometric integral

Tags: real-analysis, integration, trigonometry, trigonometric-integrals

In our book we have the manipulation
\begin{align*}
b\int\limits_0^{2\pi}\sqrt{\left(1-\left(1-\frac{a^2}{b^2}\right)\sin^2(t)\right)}~\!dt=4b\int\limits_0^{\frac{\pi}{2}}\sqrt{\left(1-\left(1-\frac{a^2}{b^2}\right)\sin^2(t)\right)}~\!dt
\end{align*}
where $a,b>0$. Where does $4$ come from and why the change of the upper integration bound to $\frac{\pi}{2}$? As the author didn't add a $4$ to $t$ inside the sine function it can't be integration by substitution, so what justifies this step?

Comment: Consider the behavior of the integrand under the reflections $t \mapsto -t$ and $t \mapsto \frac\pi2 - t$.

Comment: Have you a seen a [plot](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input?i=plot+sqrt%281+-+4%2F9+sin%5E2t%29+from+0+to+2pi) of the integrand for some fixed $a,b$?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The first integral is taken over the interval $[0, 2\pi]$, covering the full period of the sine function. The second integral is taken over the interval $[0, \frac{\pi}{2}]$, covering only one-quarter of the period of the sine function.
The integrand function is an even function, the integrand is symmetric about the $y$-axis.

If we denote the integrand as $f(t)$, then the given equation can be rewritten as:
$$
     \int_0^{2\pi} f(t) \, dt = 4 \int_0^{\frac{\pi}{2}} f(t) \, dt
  $$